# Area using integration

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, area

Suppose we have the circle
$$
(x - 5)^2 + (y - 10)^2 = 8^2.
$$

How can we find its area using simple integration (*i.e.* without polar coordinates or double integration)?

The integration I have done up until now assumed the circle's center is at the origin with standard form $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$. There we could find $\int_0^r\sqrt{r^2 - x^2}\,dx$ and multiply by $4$. Using integration, the idea is that we can first find the infinitesimal area by $f(x)\,dx$ and then sum up all the areas.

But in this nonstandard circle, I cannot come up with how to calculate the infinitesimal area. I can't seem to figure out where the $dx$ is since there is not a line parallel to the $x$-axis. So a little help on this using figure will be appreciable.

Comment: It is the same circle shifted to have centre at (5, 10) , which does not change its area.

Comment: Hint: use $dA=\frac12(xdy-ydx)$ with $x=5+8\cos t$ etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that

$$
(x-5)^2+(y-10)^2 = 8^2,
$$

one can express $y$ as a function of $x$ as follows:

$$
y = 10\pm\sqrt{8^2-(x-5)^2},
$$

where $y = 10+\sqrt{8^2-(x-5)^2}$ represents a part of the circle *above* the line $y = 10$ and $y = 10-\sqrt{8^2-(x-5)^2}$ represents a part of the circle *below* the line $y = 10$. $x\in [-3, 13]$.

Then, the area of the *upper semi-circle* will be

$$
\begin{aligned}
S_\text{upper}&=\int_{-3}^{13}\left(10+\sqrt{8^2-(x-5)^2}\right)dx-\underbrace{\int_{-3}^{13}10dx}_{\text{the area of a rectangle}\\ \text{bounded between }\\x\in[-3, 13]\text{ and }y\in[0, 10]} = \int_{-3}^{13}\sqrt{8^2-(x-5)^2}dx \\
&=\left[
\begin{array}{l}
u = x-5 \Leftrightarrow du = dx \\
u \in[-8; 8]
\end{array}
\right] = \\
&= \int_{-8}^8\sqrt{8^2-u^2}du = 2\int_0^8\sqrt{8^2-u^2}du.
\end{aligned}
$$

Then, the full area equal to $2S_\text{upper} = 4\int_0^8\sqrt{8^2-u^2}du$.

Answer (score 1):

Define the coordinates $x = X + 5$ and $y = Y + 10$. Insert these into $(x-5)^2+(y-10)^2=8^2$ to get:

$$ (X+5-5)^2+(Y+10-10)^2=8^2 \tag 1$$
$$ X^2+Y^2=8^2 \tag 2$$

Since $r=8$, you get the simple form of the equation of circle:

$$ X^2+Y^2=r^2 \tag 3$$

Keep in mind, that we have only shifted the circle so that it's center is at $(0,0)$. That means the area did not change. Now you can integrate over $Y=\sqrt{r^2-X^2}$ and multiply by $4$ to get your desired area.